# "You asked about this job" needs a year in the datestamp

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

From time to time I peruse the available jobs in the careers section, and a couple of weeks ago I saw this job:

[image: Job ad]

That's odd, I thought to myself, I'm quite sure I didn't make *any* job enquiries a couple of months ago. Ha! of course, it means 17 Dec **2013**.

Any chance someone could pop the year onto the end of that date field, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed! We now show the year if the application date is not this year.

[image: Asked]

and

[image: Applied]

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Very speedy, thanks Dean!